# Defining multiple objects of the same class in python

Tags: python, object

is there any shorthand method of defining multiple objects of the same class in one line. (I'm not talking about lists or array of objects)..

i mean something like

```
p1,p2,p3 = Point()
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What would that mean?  Can you provide some explanation of what you think that should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think map is also acceptable here:

```
p1, p2, p3 = map(lambda x: Point(), xrange(3))
```

But generator expression seems to be a bit faster:

```
p1, p2, p3 = (Point() for x in xrange(3))
```

Comment: That's a generator comprehension, not a list comprehension.

Comment: @JAB: that's [generator **expression**](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), not generator comprehension

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Considering the syntax usage elsewhere in the document, "generator comprehension" can simply be taken to mean "comprehension wrapped as a generator" rather than "as a list" or "as a dict". After all, what most people refer to as "list comprehensions" are actually "(list )comprehensions contained within list displays", as shown in the link you provided.

Comment: Thank you guys - i have modified my post.

Answer (score 6):

It may be slightly more efficient to use a generator comprehension rather than a list comprehension:

```
p1, p2, p3 = (Point() for _ in range(3)) # use xrange() in versions of Python where range() does not return an iterator for more efficiency
```

There's also the simple solution of

```
p1, p2, p3 = Point(), Point(), Point()
```

Which takes advantage of implicit tuple packing and unpacking.

Comment: ya this was exactly what I wanted..thnx

Answer (score 3):

Not really.

```
p1, p2, p3 = [Point() for x in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

This code does what you're asking, but I don't know if this is your final goal:

```
p1, p2, p3 = [Point() for _ in range(3)]
```